# Check for registered content observers

Tags: android

I'm building an app that uses content observers.
My problem is, that I tend to register my content observers multiple
times. This causes my application to log events several times.
How do I find out, if my content observer is already registered?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Better late than never...

AFAIK you can't check whether a content observer is registered so I use a Hashmap to store the observers and have a constant for each observer type to check if it needs to be registered. You could also use the URI you are registering as the key...

Comment: Further to this, I realized my hashmap wasn't being kept in memory so I have made a static synchronized class to keep track of what is registered. Does anyone have a better solution?

Comment: Hi there I've found a solution that works fine the purpose. The contentobserver resides in a service and a reference to the observer is kept as a property of the service. By making the property static it is shared among instances of the service. If it is null, the contentobserver is not registered and the service is allowed to register the observer. If the property is not null, then no other instance of the service has registered this contentobserver. My solution is very specific to my case. It seems that your solution is more generic. Thanks for the answer :-)